# How do I use yq to change dns severs in a yaml?

Tags: yaml, netplan

Here is my yaml file:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
      - 10.200.2.148/22
      gateway4: 10.200.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 2.2.2.2
        - 3.3.3.3
        - 4.4.4.4
        search:
        - our.domain
```

I need to replace all dns addresses under ens160 to two specific addresses.
Tried using this:

```
yq write -i /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml  '.network.ethernets.ens160.nameservers.addresses' ['10.10.10.53','10.10.10.54']
```

but all that did was shift all the list items in one like this:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
        - 10.200.2.148/22
      gateway4: 10.200.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 2.2.2.2
          - 3.3.3.3
          - 4.4.4.4
        search:
          - our.domain
```

I dont want that. I need the output to look like this

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
      - 10.200.2.148/22
      gateway4: 10.200.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 10.10.10.53
        - 10.10.10.54
        search:
        - our.domain
```

Its not very clear how I can do this with `yq`, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Didn't you ask a [very similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/740952/edit-netplan-yaml-with-only-awk-and-sed-to-change-dns-servers) 20 minutes earlier?

Comment: This is how to use yq for systems I can use yq for.

Comment: Which `yq` command are you using? What does `yq --version` output? There are two competing variants of YAML parsing tools, both called `yq`, and they are used differently.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason I could not get the version that is in the apt repository to work at all.

I ended up installing the latest version, and it works with this command

```
yq -i '.network.ethernets.ens160.nameservers.addresses = ["10.10.10.53","10.10.10.54"]' /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Not being overly familiar with [Mike Farah's `yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/), I would probably pass in a JSON array of new name server addresses via an environment variable and then insert it at the correct path in the document using `env()`:

```bash
$ addrs='["10.10.10.53","10.10.10.54"]' yq '.network.ethernets.ens160.nameservers.addresses = env(addrs)' file
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
        - 10.200.2.148/22
      gateway4: 10.200.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: ["10.10.10.53", "10.10.10.54"]
        search:
          - our.domain
```

Add the `-i` option to do the transformation "in-place", and use `-P` to pretty print the output (this would unwrap the array onto several lines, as in the expected output in the question).

Mike Farah's `yq` can't, as far as I'm aware, be made to take an arbitrary number of separate arguments as an array without encoding them into a JSON array, as in the command above.  With [Andrey Kislyuk's `yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), which is a wrapper around the well-known `jq` JSON processor, one may instead do this:

```bash
$ yq -y '.network.ethernets.ens160.nameservers.addresses = $ARGS.positional' file --args 10.10.10.53 10.10.10.54
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
        - 10.200.2.148/22
      gateway4: 10.200.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 10.10.10.53
          - 10.10.10.54
        search:
          - our.domain
```

... which is almost the same thing we had with Mike's `yq`, but allowing us to add further name server addresses by appending them at the end of the command line.  Since `$ARGS.positional` is always an array, the resulting document would contain a properly formatted list of a single element if only one string was given on the command line.

This `yq` does "in-place" editing if you use it with its `-i` or `--in-place` option.